# Lowenheim-Skolem number for satisfaction via continuous function rings

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, logic, set-theory, model-theory

*EDIT: now [asked at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401258/a-topological-version-of-the-lowenheim-skolem-number).*

For $\mathcal{X}$ a topological space, let $C(\mathcal{X})$ be the ring of continuous functions $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. For a first-order sentence $\varphi$ in the language of rings, write $\mathcal{X}\models_{C}\varphi$ iff $C(\mathcal{X})\models\varphi$ in the usual sense. Say that $\varphi$ is ***C*-satisfiable** iff $\mathcal{X}\models_C\varphi$ for some topological space $\mathcal{X}$.

I'm generally curious about analogues of classical model-theoretic questions in this context. For example:

> What is the least cardinal $\kappa$ such that, if $\varphi$ is $C$-satisfiable, then $\mathcal{X}\models_C\varphi$ for some space $\mathcal{X}$ with cardinality $<\kappa$?

The obvious Lowenheim-Skolem argument doesn't help much here. Roughly speaking, given $\mathcal{X}\models_C\varphi$ we can form a "small" elementary substructure $(\mathcal{Y}, R)$ in the usual first-order sense of (an appropriate version of) the pair $(\mathcal{X},C(\mathcal{X}))$. However, in general we might have $R\subsetneq C(\mathcal{Y})$ (this is similar to the distinction between Henkin and standard semantics for second-order logic).

*(Of course number of points isn't the only cardinal invariant for which we could ask a Lowenheim-Skolem flavored question, but it seems the simplest to start with. Another natural thing to do would be to restrict attention to a "nice" class of spaces, e.g. the [compact Hausdorff spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gelfand-Kolmogorov+theorem), but again this seems like a better first step.)*

One issue here is that I don't know an abstract characterization of which rings are isomorphic to some $C(\mathcal{X})$. Obviously any such ring $R$ must be the underlying ring of a commutative associative unital $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, but beyond that I don't see anything. I recall seeing a very snappy theorem addressing this, but I can't find it at the moment (I *think* it was more complicated than just "any commutative associative unital $\mathbb{R}$-algebra's underlying ring," but I'm not certain).

---

My broader interest incidentally is in what happens if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ with some other topological structure *(= first-order structure + topology such that all functions are continuous and all relations are closed, as subsets of the appropriate product space)*. Given a topological structure $\mathcal{A}$ and a topological space $\mathcal{X}$ we can always turn the set of continuous maps from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{A}$ into a structure of the same type as $\mathcal{A}$ by defining everything "pointwise." So for each topological structure $\mathcal{A}$ we get an analogue $\models_C^\mathcal{A}$ of the relation $\models_C$ above.

Ultimately my interest is in developing a connection between "coarse" model-theoretic properties (e.g. variants of the Lowenheim-Skolem number) of $\models_C^\mathcal{A}$ and topological algebraic properties of $\mathcal{A}$. While this question specifically asks about $\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{R}$, if anyone has information about a different ("nontrivial") $\mathcal{A}$ or class of $\mathcal{A}$s I'd be very interested.

Comment: You might want to look up the Gelfand representation theorem.

Comment: @ZhenLin Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't immediately see how to use that here?

Comment: You asked for a characterisation of rings of continuous functions...

Comment: I don't have any specific insights, but you might want to look at Woodin and Dales' work on these kinds of algebras. I don't recall any mention of LS type theorems, but it's a fairly large body of knowledge which might have some useful stuff. Look for instance at Woodin and Dales' *Super-Real Fields*. There's also Dales' giant Automatic Continuity book, but it's more from the analysis point of view.

Comment: @Reveillark I'm (very slightly) familiar with some of that material, but I don't immediately see any direct relevance. That said, it's very cool stuff and I always enjoy reading it!

Comment: Yeah, to be honest I don't see explicit relevance either, but I thought I'd suggest it just in case (since it's a mix of logic and that particular branch of analysis). And I agree, the independence of Kaplansky's Conjecture is a thing of beauty. 

Also, if you don't get any answers here, the person to ask is probably Ilijas Farah. Have you looked at his book *Combinatorial Set Theory of $C^*$-algebras*? There is a lot of continuous model theory there.

Comment: @ZhenLin Maybe I'm not looking at the right theorem, but Gelfand representation doesn't seem to tell me exactly which rings have that form. What version of the representation theorem do you have in mind?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but we have a good handle on this in the special case of a finitely-generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $A$. In that case, $\text{MaxSpec}(A)$ is actually a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and we can identify $f \in A$ with the function $\mathfrak{m} \mapsto f/\mathfrak{m} : \text{MaxSpec}(A) \to \mathbb{C}$. This is an inclusion $A \hookrightarrow C(\text{MaxSpec}(A))$ (where now I'm considering complex functions), whenever the [jacobson radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical) of $A$ is trivial. See, eg, Neeman's _Algebraic and Analytic Geometry_.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Sorry, what is MaxSpec? I'm not very familiar with functional analysis.

Comment: This is _also_ not exactly what you want, but it's more general: have you seen the characterization that $\text{MaxSpec}(A)$ is hausdorff if and only if $A / J(A)$ (where $J$ is the jacobson radical again) is a [gelfand ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_ring)? There's a paper (Schwarz and Tressl's _Elementary Properties of Minimal and Maximal Points in Zariski Spectra_) which goes over some topological properties of $\text{MaxSpec}(A)$ that you can recover from properties of $A$ definable in the language of rings.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Ooh, nice (and I haven't seen that characterization). Still, as far as I can tell none of this answers "Which rings are isomorphic to $C(X)$ for some space $X$?" or the question of the OP above; am I missing something, or is that accurate?

Comment: Sorry! $\text{MaxSpec}(A)$ is the space whose points are the maximal ideals of $A$. There are multiple topologies one can put on this -- normally we use the [zariski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology), but in some cases we can also use the so called "complex topology", which makes it a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks. Can you clarify for me - when you initially wrote "we have a good handle on this," what did "this" refer to? (Sorry, I'm just not very familiar with functional analysis or algebra, so I often miss the implications of important facts.)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm only leaving comments, unfortunately. In the special case of fg-$\mathbb{C}$-algebras with trivial jacobson radical, we always have an embedding $A \hookrightarrow C(\text{MaxSpec}(A))$, but this is almost never surjective (in fact, it picks out exactly the polynomial functions on this subvariety of $\mathbb{C}^n$). I'm more familiar with algebraic geometry than I am with the more general dualities you find in functional analysis, and I unfortunately don't know enough about $C^*$ algebras or Gelfand Duality to say more.

Comment: Of course! By "this" I meant "representing $A$ as a ring of continuous functions on some space". Though, again, we miss out on many of the continuous functions on $\text{MaxSpec}(A)$, since this only gives us the polynomial functions. Still, it's an embedding, which gets us part of the way there.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor OK, that clarifies things - thanks a ton!

Answer (score 7):

This is not even close to a complete answer, but it at least shows that $\text{ZFC}\vdash\kappa>2^{\aleph_0}$, so I will record it here. Let $$\varphi\equiv\forall u\left[u^2=u\to(u=0\vee u=1)\right]$$ be the sentence expressing that there are no non-trivial idempotents. Then $\mathcal{X}\models_C\varphi$ if and only if $\mathcal{X}$ is connected. To see this, first suppose $\mathcal{X}$ is disconnected, say with a decomposition $\mathcal{X}=U\sqcup V$ for non-empty open subsets $U,V$; then the map $\alpha:\mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $x\mapsto 0$ if $x\in U$ and $x\mapsto 1$ if $x\in V$ is a non-trivial idempotent element of $C(\mathcal{X})$. Conversely, suppose $C(\mathcal{X})$ has a non-trivial idempotent $\alpha$. Since the ring $\mathbb{R}$ has no non-trivial idempotents, we have $\alpha(x)\in\{0,1\}$ for each $x\in\mathcal{X}$; since also $\alpha\neq 0,1$, we have that $\alpha^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $\alpha^{-1}(\{1\})$ are both non-empty. This gives a partition of $\mathcal{X}$ into disjoint non-trivial open subsets, whence $\mathcal{X}$ is not connected.

Now let $\psi\equiv \exists u\left[u\neq 0\wedge\forall v(u\cdot v\neq 1)\right]$. I claim that $\varphi\wedge\psi$ is $C$-satisfiable, but that $\mathcal{X}\not\models_C\varphi\wedge\psi$ for any $\mathcal{X}$ whose cardinality is smaller than $2^{\aleph_0}$. To see that it is $C$-satisfiable, note that, for example, $\mathbb{R}\models_C\varphi\wedge\psi$, where $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology. Indeed, $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, so $\mathbb{R}\models_C\varphi$ by the remarks above; furthermore, the function $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto 0$ when $x\leqslant 0$ and $x\mapsto x$ when $x\geqslant 0$ is a non-invertible non-zero element of $C(\mathcal{X})$, whence $\mathbb{R}\models_C\psi$ as well.

To see that $\mathcal{X}\not\models_C\varphi\wedge\psi$ for any $\mathcal{X}$ of cardinality smaller than $2^{\aleph_0}$, suppose that $|\mathcal{X}|<2^{\aleph_0}$ and that $\mathcal{X}\models_C\varphi$. Then $\mathcal{X}$ is connected by the remarks in the first paragraph, so for any $\alpha\in C(\mathcal{X})$ the subspace $\alpha(\mathcal{X})\subset\mathbb{R}$ is connected as well. Connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely intervals; since $|\mathcal{X}|<2^{\aleph_0}$, this forces each $\alpha(\mathcal{X})$ to be a singleton. So every element of $C(\mathcal{X})$ is a constant function, whence $C(\mathcal{X})\cong\mathbb{R}$ as rings, whence $\mathcal{X}\models_C\neg\psi$, as desired.

Comment: Quite nice, thanks!

Comment: @NoahSchweber my pleasure, happy it helped! :) the more set-theoretic side of things is completely outside my wheelhouse, and I have no intuition at all for what might at larger cardinalities, but I will be very curious to see if you or others are able to sharpen the bounds!

Comment: As an aside, note that things are much easier if we ask about the "sub(space)structure" version of Lowenheim-Skolem (that is, given $\mathcal{X}\models_C\varphi$, how small a subspace of $\mathcal{X}$ can we find which also yields a model of $\varphi$?): take for example a connected $\mathcal{X}$ all of whose proper subspaces are disconnected (such as $\mathbb{R}$ itself).

Comment: @NoahSchweber true, that's a very good point! (I just saw your new post on that question as well.) so I guess that definitely rules out the possibility of a general construction for taking a space $\mathcal{X}$ with $\mathcal{X}\models_C\varphi$ and finding a subspace $\mathcal{Y}\subset\mathcal{X}$ of strictly smaller cardinality with $\mathcal{Y}\models_C\varphi$. (do you know if it is possible to find connected spaces of arbitrarily large cardinality all of whose strictly smaller subspaces are disconnected? I strongly suspect yes but I can't think of a construction off the top of my head)

Comment: Sure - any connected linear order (thought of as a space, via the order topology) has the "all proper subspaces disconnected" property, so we just need to find arbitrarily large connected linear orders. This is handled by the usual Dedekind completion construction, starting with an arbitrary *dense* linear order of high cardinality. (Incidentally, back in the realm of nicer spaces $\mathbb{R}^2$, or $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$, is a more interesting example - it has lots of connected proper subspaces but no connected subspace of smaller cardinality.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber oh nice, that's a useful general construction! but wait, sorry if I'm being dense, but when you say "proper subspace" do you mean subspace of strictly smaller cardinality, or just any subspace not equal to the whole space? (if the latter, then why wouldn't for example the interval $(0,1)$ be a connected proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}$?)

Comment: Whoops, you're right, "proper" should be "of smaller cardinality." I wanted to emphasize the "lots" in the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$: while $\mathbb{R}$ has very few connected subspaces even up to ambient homeomorphism (seveight if I'm counting correctly), $\mathbb{R}^2$ has [too many to classify](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054404/is-there-a-way-to-generalize-the-connected-sets-in-mathbbr2/4054409#4054409). Also, my "arbitrary" dense linear order above should have all intervals large. I'm not good at precision right now. :P

Comment: @NoahSchweber that makes sense entirely, thank you... I find that somewhat surprising! although it certainly makes sense with a bit of thought

Comment: I've awarded this the bounty and [passed the broader question on to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401258/a-topological-version-of-the-lowenheim-skolem-number).

Comment: @NoahSchweber right on, I will be very keen to see what answers you get on MO; thank you for the bounty!!

Comment: (To preemptively clarify, I've unaccepted and removed my comment since the MO answer showing that this answer is optimal turned out to be flawed.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber no problem!! bummer that Rahman's argument turned out not to work... it certainly sounds plausible to me that $\kappa=(2^{\aleph_0})^+$, I wonder if someone will be able to correct the argument!

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathcal Y\Vdash \phi$ for some **compact Hausdorff space** $\mathcal Y$ then $\mathcal X\Vdash \phi$ for some compact Hausdorff $\mathcal X$ of cardinality $\leq \beth_2.$ So a "compact Hausdorff satisfiability" version of your question has $\kappa\leq\beth_2^+.$ I don't know how to improve your bound in the general case, or whether $\beth_2^+$ is optimal for the compact Hausdorff case.

Fix a compact Hausdorff $\mathcal Y.$ We will try to find a space $\mathcal X$ of cardinality $\leq\beth_2$ that is elementarily equivalent to $\mathcal Y.$

Let $B(\mathcal Y)$ denote the set of continuous functions $\mathcal Y\to[-1,1].$ The approach will be to take a subset $A\subset B(\mathcal Y)$ of cardinality $\leq\mathfrak c$ that is “countably saturated with respect to $B(\mathcal Y)$” in the sense that for any countable $F\subseteq A,$ any type $\Lambda(f)$ over $A$ that is realized in $B(\mathcal Y)$ is also realized by a scalar multiple of an element of $A.$

Introduce variables $x_i, i<\mathfrak c.$
For each $\alpha\in\mathfrak c$ pick a 1-type $\Lambda_\alpha$ over a countable subset of $\{x_\beta:\beta<\alpha\},$ such that every such type gets hit at some point. Then build $A$ by transfinite iteration, where at step $\alpha$ we add a realization $f_\alpha\in B(\mathcal Y),$ if any exists, for the type $\Lambda_\alpha(f)$ with variables $x_\beta$ replaced by $f_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha,$ and set $f_\alpha=0$ otherwise.

Let $P$ be the product $[-1,1]^A.$ Take $\mathcal X$ to be the image of $\phi:\mathcal Y\to P,$ where $x$ is sent to $a\mapsto a(x).$ Consider a continuous function $f:\mathcal X\to\mathbb R.$ Since $\mathcal X$ is compact, $f$ is bounded, so it is an integer multiple of a function $f/k$ with values in $[-1,1].$ I claim that $f/k$ is already a scalar multiple of a function in $A.$ We can extend $f/k$ to a function $g:P\to[-1,1].$

This $g$ factors through the projection $[-1,1]^A\to[-1,1]^{A_0}$ for some countable $A_0.$ One way to see this is that the preimage of each closed interval $[a,b]$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Q$ is a compact $G_\delta,$ which can be written as a countable intersection of finite unions of basic opens. So $g$ is continuous using the topology on $[-1,1]^A$ generated by basic opens using indices in some countable $A_0.$ But $g$ will then already be uniquely specified by some type over $A_0,$ and hence will already be in $A.$ The countable saturation, in fact just finite saturation, shows that $\mathcal Y$ is an elementary submodel of $\mathcal X.$ Note $|\mathcal Y|\leq \beth_2.$

**Remarks.**

1. C. Ward Henson studied a related question in “Nonstandard hulls of Banach spaces”, for positive bounded formulas.
2. For general spaces there is a ring isomorphism $C(\mathcal X)\cong C(\mathcal Y)$ if and only if the “Hewitt realcompactifications” of $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$ are homeomorphic. I’m not sure this helps directly, but it might be <strike>what you were thinking of as a characterization</strike> interesting.
3. Some papers (at least Henson's) talk in terms of Banach algebras. For the compact Hausdorff case we're talking about (the ring reduct of) the real Banach algebra $C(\mathcal X).$ There is a bi-interpretation of complex arithmetic with complex conjugation, so we could equivalently talk about complex Banach algebras.
4. My guess is that we can always take $\mathcal X$ to be a Polish space. Perhaps we can take $A$ to be a countable sequence of generic functions, i.e. an element in a comeager set of $B(\mathcal Y)^\omega.$

Comment: Re: 2, no - I was looking for a characterization of when a ring $\mathfrak{R}$ is isomorphic to $C(\mathcal{A})$ for some space $\mathcal{A}$, not when two spaces yield the same ring (although of course that's an interesting question too - and I hadn't heard of Hewit realcompactifications before).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I just noticed the first step doesn’t make sense - I can’t express “being finite” with this encoding so I can’t reduce to the compact hausdorff case. Is the compact hausdorff case still interesting?

Comment: Compact Hausdorff is definitely still interesting! (My suspicion though is that that's a sufficiently strong condition that it changes the answer.)

Comment: dear Harry, I haven't read through your post in detail, but this looks like a nice approach (+1); do you think the argument is salvageable? I will note that there are $C$-satisfiable theories (in the language of rings+a single new constant symbol) none of whose $\models_C$-models are compact; for example, define a formula $$u>v\equiv \exists w\big[u-v=w^2\big]\wedge\exists w\big[(u-v)w=1\big].$$ then we have $C(\mathcal{X})\models \alpha>\beta$ iff $\alpha(x)>\beta(x)$ for all $x\in \mathcal{X}$. now, define a theory $T$ in the language of rings with a single new constant symbol $a$ ...

Comment: ... by taking $T$ to contain sentences $\neg(a<n)$ for each $n\in\omega$. then $T$ is $C$-satisfiable, eg by taking $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}$ and realizing $a$ as $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$, but not $C$-satisfiable by any compact $\mathcal{X}$, since continuous images of compact spaces are compact, and all compact subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ are bounded

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom: I certainly don’t think it can easily be salvaged - what you’ve just said shows that we would need to use some special property of the language of rings (without an extra constant symbol) to get full elementary equivalence to a compact space