# Name/source for cardinal invariant in topology

Tags: general-topology, logic, reference-request, set-theory, terminology

Given a topological space $\mathcal{X}=(X,\tau)$ and a set $A\subseteq X$, say that $A$ is $\mathcal{X}$-*sufficient* iff every continuous function $(A,\tau_A)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ extends to a unique continuous function $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (where we equip $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology). Let $\mathfrak{suff}(\mathcal{X})$ be the smallest cardinality of an $\mathcal{X}$-sufficient set; **what is the general term for this** (and what are some good sources)?

Note that we can replace $\mathbb{R}$ with any topological space $\mathcal{C}$ here and get the analogous notions $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{C})$-sufficiency and and $\mathfrak{suff}_\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{X})$. Changing the target space, even staying in the realm of "rich" target spaces, can drastically alter the value of the relevant sufficiency cardinal. For example, $\mathfrak{suff}(\mathbb{R})=2^{\aleph_0}$, since every disconnected subspace admits a continuous function to $\mathbb{R}$ not extendible to all of $\mathbb{R}$ and every subspace missing an interval has too many continuous extensions of (say) the constant-zero function (so the only sufficient subspace is $\mathbb{R}$ itself), but $\mathfrak{suff}_\mathcal{\mathcal{D}}(\mathbb{R})=1$ for every totally disconnected $\mathcal{D}$. I'm more broadly interested in the whole function $\mathfrak{suff}_{-}(-)$, but the specific case $\mathcal{C}=\mathbb{R}$ seems more likely to have a lot of material easily available.

*(This is related to [a variation of this recent question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4211730/lowenheim-skolem-number-for-satisfaction-via-continuous-function-rings#comment8748889_4214251) - basically, given a first-order sentence $\varphi$ and a space $\mathcal{X}$ with $C(\mathcal{X},\mathbb{R})\models\varphi$, how small a subspace $\mathcal{Y}\subseteq\mathcal{X}$ can I find such that $C(\mathcal{Y},\mathbb{R})\models\varphi$?)*

Comment: Interesting question (can't add anything helpful).  There might be a word missing here:  "since any proper subspace of R is disconnected and ..."

Comment: @Randall Nope, that's right as written (I did almost type "write as righten" just now, though :P): "and so" could be replaced with "and therefore" or etc.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti $$x\mapsto\begin{cases}0 &\mbox{if }x<\pi\\ 1 & \mbox{ if }x>\pi.\\\end{cases}$$ (That said, I did write that every proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is disconnected, which ... is bonkers.)

Comment: Ah of course, I want uniform continuity to extend from a dense subset

Comment: Actually isn't $A=\Bbb R$ the only subspace of $\Bbb R$ that works? That seems reasonable since for completely regular spaces the ring of continuous real valued functions determines the space

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Yes, exactly: a proper subspace either has a cut point or misses an interval. I've edited to make this explicit.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136554/generalizations-of-the-tietze-extension-theorem-and-lusins-theorem

Comment: If $X$ has a point $x\in X$ such that $x$ is a limit of some non-constant sequence and $U=X\backslash\{x\}$ is normal then this $suff(X)=|X|$. That's because we take a sequence $(x_n)$ convergent to $x$ inside $U$. This sequence is closed in $U$ and thus by Tietze any function $f:\{x_n\}\to\mathbb{R}$ extends to $U$. We can choose $f$ so that $f(x_n)$ diverges. In that case the extension $F:U\to\mathbb{R}$ cannot be extended further to full $X$. In particular this makes all hereditary normal, first countable spaces (for example all metrizable spaces) trivial, right?