# What is the cardinality of a connected separable toplogical space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a nontrivial topological space. Assume ZFC.

If $X$ is a first countable compact $T_2$ space, then $|X|\leq c$.

If  $X$ is a first countable separable $T_2$ space, then $|X|\leq c$.

Since second countability implies first countability and separability, I am guessing that:

If $X$ is a second countable $T_2$ space, then $|X|\leq c$.

My question:

1. What is the cardinality of a connected separable $T_2$ space?
2. What is the cardinality of a second countable $T_1$ space?

Comment: In your second line, did you mean $T1$ instead of $T2$?

Comment: @Chickenmancer Yes

Comment: The Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb R$ has cardinality $2^c$, and it's connected and separable because $\mathbb R$ is.

Comment: And @AndreasBlass' observation is optimal, by a special case of the argument presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4216332/28111).

Comment: @AndreasBlass So it seems like the cardinality of connected separable T2 space is less than or equal to $2^c$?

Comment: @HighGPA The cardinality of any separable Hausdorff space (connected or not) is bounded by $2^c$. More generally, a Hausdorff space with a dense subset of size $\kappa$ cannot be larger than $2^{2^\kappa}$. The reason is that every point is the limit of a different filter on the dense set, and there are only $2^{2^\kappa}$ filters on a set of size $\kappa$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So the property of "connected" does not usually impose a restriction on cardinality?

Comment: @HighGPA That depends a lot on "usually". For example, normal ( = T1 + T4) spaces can have any cardinality at all, but connected ones can't have cardinalities strictly between $1$ and $c$. So in that situation, connectedness definitely affects cardinality.

Comment: There are a few countable, connected, Hausdorff ($T_{2}$) spaces listed on the $\pi$-base

https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=countable%2Bconnected%2Bhausdorff